# phpinfo() in query_string clear $_GET variables

Tags: php, function, search, get, query-string

Hi im trying to make a form with a textbox to search words and functions.

but when i search phpinfo( or phpinfo() all $_GET variables are empty.
for example

```
<form name="search-form" method="GET" action"results.php">
<input name="search-input" value = "" type="text"/>
<input name="search-submit" value ="Submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

if i search anything and print

```
print_r($_GET);
```

works
but when i search phpinfo( or phpinfo()
and i print with print_r($_GET) returns array() all the times.

why is this happen?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "search phpinfo()"? Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: well i have this html form when i subitted to results.php i echo out print_r($_GET) but is empty if i include the word "phpinfo()" in the search

Comment: @user953510 - If you are not actually getting a crash, I suggest you edit the question title and make it less misleading.

Answer (score 2):

You should ask your hosting provider. The symptoms suggest there's a security module out there (maybe [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/)) filtering out your query strings with a black list.

Comment: well but at least should return something like phpinfo() in htmlentities, but crash all $_GET

Comment: What does HTML have to do with this?

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. It could be the Suhosin patch